# How do you order by multiple columns using AMPScript LookupOrderedRows?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Using the [LookupOrderedRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) function is it possible to list multiple columns? If not, how have people approached this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list mutliple columns. In parameter 3 you can define multiple field names and order combination delimited by comma, example would be:

```
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Cars",4,"field1 Desc, field2 Desc","MPG",Field(@cardata,"MPG"))
```